# Add to a table row a "paragraph" html

Tags: html, css, row, paragraph

is it possible to add a paragraph to a table row? Its length should be equal to the length of the line and be below it (as in the picture)

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr{
  border:1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>Surname </th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amelia</td>
    <td>Evans</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <p>*This is an Example of text </p>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emily</td>
    <td>Wilson</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jessica</td>
    <td>Ellington</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

```
      <tr>
        <td>Amelia</td>
        <td>Evans</td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3"><p style="text-align:justify">*This is an Example of text </p></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

so in order to do what your asking, you will need to use bootstrap which is what ARLEQUINA is showing you.

here is the link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

you can download the files for it or you can just use a link to import it. You will only need to import the CSS style sheet and not the JavaScript stuff unless your using JavaScript which might be useful.

bootstrap is straight forward and there is a lot of documentation on it. Once you've imported bootstrap to your project all you'll need to do is add the following:

`<td colspan="3"><p style="text-align:justify">This is an Example of text </p></td>`

Comment: is it valid html to put a `p` tag within `td`?